# how to drop rows where the index succeed another index value in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, this slice i need to drop the consecutives ones, and keep the last. For example, 115 succeeds 114, so i should drop 114.

```
108    3
114    3
115    4
123    3
124    4
125    5
```

The desired dataframe would be:

```
108    3
115    4
125    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), and filter no `-1` rows, it means first consecutive duplciates are removed:

*Notice*: Because `index.diff` is not implemented, is used [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for convert `index` to `Series`.

```
df1 = df[df.index.to_series().diff(-1).ne(-1)]
print (df1)
     a
108  3
115  4
125  5
```

If need filter by values in column, e.g. `a`:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('a')
print (df2)
     a
108  3
115  4
125  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question says *last* but expected output is *first* both provided for reference.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""108    3
114    3
115    4
123    3
124    4
125    5"""),sep="\s+", header=None).set_index(0)

print(df.reset_index().groupby(1, as_index=False).first().set_index(0).to_markdown())
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 108 | 3 |
| 115 | 4 |
| 125 | 5 |

```
print(df.reset_index().groupby(1, as_index=False).last().set_index(0).to_markdown())
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 |
| 124 | 4 |
| 125 | 5 |